# HTML5 : getImageData with onmousemove make slow my application in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, getimagedata

I create a little html5 game with canvas.

In the canvas, there are many displayed sprites and one of them move automatically from left to right. The others are statics.

When I move the mouse onto the canvas, I draw all sprites in a temporary canvas and I use getImageData to find the sprite onto which the mouse is over.

But getImageData make slow anormally the moving sprite in Firefox.

So what is the solution to avoid this deceleration ?

Here my code :

```
function getSelectedObject(array_objects)
{
    //Clear the temporary canvas :
    tmpcx.clearRect(0, 0, tmpc.width, tmpc.height);

    /*Search the right sprite object :*/
    for(var i = array_objects.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        array_objects[i].draw(tmpcx);

        imageData = tmpcx.getImageData(mouse_x, mouse_y, 1, 1);

        component = imageData.data;

        if(component[3] > 0)
        {   
            //Return the sprite object found : 
            return array_objects[i];
        }

        else
        {
            tmpcx.clearRect(0, 0, tmpc.width, tmpc.height);
        }
    }

    return false;
}


canvas.onmousemove = function(event)
{

selectedObject = getSelectedObject(array_objects);

}
```

Comment: So what is the solution to avoid this deceleration ?

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to *accomplish* here. You want a moving sprite on a canvas that tracks the mouse position?

Comment: The moving sprite is just to check the performance of the application : if the moving sprite decelerate, that means the application have bad performance. Normally, the moving sprite mustn't decelerate.

Comment: Constantly drawing and erasing on a temporary canvas seems needlessly expensive. There's two suggestions I'd have for this:
1. Use two canvases for your game, one to render the background and anything that's just decorative, and another for the interactive elements that you want to track.
2. Store the coordinates for the bounding boxes of each sprite. That way, you can check first to see if the mouse is over something interactive, then you can use the coordinates to figure out which element it's inside of

Comment: Jaromanda, to detect a sprite in the tmp canvas, the mouseover found the blue component => it's a bad solution ?

Comment: What I don't understand is *why* you are looping through the sprites and drawing/reading canvas data. That's a *super* expensive 'performance test'.

Comment: @Jaromanda, yes i use alpha component to find the sprite, but it makes slow the application in Firefox. What do you suggest ?

Comment: @jmcgriz  "Use two canvases for your game, one to render the background and anything that's just decorative, and another for the interactive elements that you want to track." What is your way to find element onto which the mouse is over ? alpha pixel detection ?

Comment: @JaredSmith   What is your way to find element onto which the mouse is over ? alpha pixel detection ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104186/discussion-between-totoaussi-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how much of a performance gain you'd get with this - no need to clear the temp canvas between sprites .... the pixel is clear until a sprite is painted on it!

I've referenced a function called `checkBoundingBoxisOver` - not sure if you could write this function, but I can't right now - besides, I don't even know what your `array_objects` are!!!

I would think it were simple, just need the x, y, width, height of a sprite to do a preliminary check if the sprite could even possibly be under the mouse before doing the expensive draw

```
function getSelectedObject(array_objects) {
    //Clear the temporary canvas :
    tmpcx.clearRect(0, 0, tmpc.width, tmpc.height);
    var sprite;
    /*Search the right sprite object :*/
    for (var i = array_objects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        sprite = array_objects[i];

        if (checkBoundingBoxisOver(sprite, mouse_x, mouse_y)) {

            sprite.draw(tmpcx);
            imageData = tmpcx.getImageData(mouse_x, mouse_y, 1, 1);
            component = imageData.data;
            if (component[3] > 0) {
                return sprite;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it !  Checking firstly if the boundling box is over before checking pixel alpha is a great idea !

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue reading pixels from a large bitmap every frame of the animation. In my case it is a black and white image showing where the world is water or land.

getImageData is extremely slow on Firefox even when reading just a single pixel.

My solution is to call getImageData only once and store the result in a imageData variable

```
    var imageData = self.context.getImageData(0,0,image.width, image.height);
```

Then you can make repeated calls to the image data and pull out the part of the image you want. In my case I just need a single pixel or a single color which looks like this

```
    var pixelRed = this.imageData.data[(y* imageWidth * 4) + (x * 4)] == 0;
```

x and y are self explanatory and since the pixels are 4 byte values (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha) I need to multiply my array index by 4. It proves to be very fast for me.

It be pretty easy to use this code to grab any portion out of the array directly as long as it is not too big.