# Why does canvas performance drop into a ditch after sleep(0)?

Tags: performance, firefox, browser, html5-canvas

I am working on an in-browser image processing tool, and have run into a bizarre performance issue in Firefox.

If I modify a canvas, then immediately get the canvas' image data, data is retrieved at the expected fast speed.
If I modify a canvas, `await` anything, *then* get the image data, this takes orders of magnitude longer.

I have reduced the issue to a minimal example, provided below. This example consists of two tests. `Test 1` writes to the canvas, then immediately simulates some canvas work by calculating the average luminosity of the canvas' pixels on a column-by-column basis. `Test 2` writes to the canvas, goes to sleep for 0ms, then simulates the same work.

As an entirely unscientific sample, running this test on my desktop (Win10, i7-5820K, 16GB RAM, GeForce GT 1030,  Firefox 90.0.2) produces these values for different canvas sizes:

```
Canvas size         Test 1 (ms)        Test 2 (ms)       ΔFactor
 512x 512                  8.0              170.0            21x
1024x1024                 31.0             1116.0            36x
2048x2048                109.0             8720.0            80x
4096x4096                631.0            76447.0           121x
8192x8192               3415.0              n/a*)           n/a     *) Script terminated by timeout
```

During the runtime, Firefox did not consume an extraordinary amount of memory. However, the tab's thread was consistently and fully loading its CPU core throughout.

Chrome does not exhibit this behavior, completing the 8192x8192 tests in 5428ms and 4536ms respectively.

Can anyone explain this?

**canvas.html**:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script defer src="canvas.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
            <button id="test1">Run Test 1</button>
            <div id="test1-result"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
            <button id="test2">Run Test 2</button>
            <div id="test2-result"></div>
        </div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

**canvas.js**:

```js
window.sleep = ((ms) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms)));

const SIZE = 2048;
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

let doSetup = (() =>
{
    canvas.width = SIZE;
    canvas.height = SIZE;
    
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,SIZE,SIZE);
});

let doTest = (() =>
{
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let sum = 0;
    for (let x=0; x<SIZE; ++x)
    {
        const data = ctx.getImageData(x,0,1,SIZE);
        for (let i=0; i<data.data.length; i+=4)
            sum += (data.data[i+0]*.299 + data.data[i+1]*.587 + data.data[i+2]*.114);
    }
    return sum/SIZE/SIZE;
});

document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener('click', async () =>
{
    doSetup();
    
    /* await sleep(0); */
    
    const start = performance.now();
    const result = doTest();
    const elapsed = (performance.now() - start);
    document.getElementById('test1-result').innerText = ('Test1 done, took '+elapsed+'ms, avg lum='+result);
});

document.getElementById('test2').addEventListener('click', async () =>
{
    doSetup();
    
    await sleep(0);
    
    const start = performance.now();
    const result = doTest();
    const elapsed = (performance.now() - start);
    document.getElementById('test2-result').innerText = ('Test2 done, took '+elapsed+'ms, avg lum='+result);
});
```

Comment: Adding `ctx.fillRect(0,0,0,0);` as a second line to `doTest` eliminates the slow-down. Bizarre.

Comment: Fetching the entire image's data at once (as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37670540) then iterating over it improves performance to a stable 2.2s on the 8192x8192 test.